# Rational points on the "quintic circle" $x^5 + y^5 = 7$

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-equations, rational-points

I suspect that the curve $x^5 + y^5=7$ has no $\mathbb Q$ points, and a brief computer search verifies this hypothesis for denominators up to $10^4$. What techniques can be used to show that there are no solutions?

Comment: It helps to instead consider the corresponding projective curve $X^5 + Y^5 = 7Z^5$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ of genus $6$. This has a rational point, namely $(X:Y:Z) = (1:-1:0)$. Your conjecture is that this is the only rational point. The similarity here to the $n=5$ case of Fermat's last theorem should be very clear. Of course the proof of FLT for all $n$ was very hard, however there exist elementary proofs for the $n=5$ case (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Fermat's_Last_Theorem_for_specific_exponents). Perhaps these could be adapted to your case.

Comment: The modular techniques and Frey curve machinery used to prove FLT could also possibly be made to apply in your case, but I am not an expert in these methods.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is an action of $\mu_5$, the group of fifth roots of unity, on your curve,
given by $\zeta \cdot (x,y) = (\zeta x, \zeta^{-1} y)$. The quotient by this
group action is the hyperelliptic curve
$$C \colon Y^2 = X^5 + \frac{49}{4},$$
the map being given by $(X, Y) = (-xy, x^5 - \frac{7}{2})$. So it is enough
to find all the rational points on $C$. $C$ is isomorphic to
$C' \colon Y^2 = 4 X^5 + 49$. By a 2-descent, one can show that the Jacobian
variety of $C'$, $J'$, has Mordell-Weil rank (at most) 1, and since one
finds a point of infinite order
($(x^2 - \frac{10}{9} x - \frac{10}{9}, \frac{200}{27} x - \frac{61}{27})$
in Mumford representation), Chabauty's method is applicable and shows
that $\infty$, $(0, \pm \frac{7}{2})$ are the only rational points on $C$.
This implies that there are no rational points on your affine curve.

Here is Magma code to check this:

> P<x> := PolynomialRing(Rationals());
>
> C := HyperellipticCurve(4*x^5 + 49);
>
> J := Jacobian(C);
>
> RankBound(J); // --> 1
>
> ptsJ := Points(J : Bound := 500); // the first 5 are torsion
>
> Chabauty(ptsJ[6]); // --> { (0 : -7 : 1), (1 : 0 : 0), (0 : 7 : 1) }

(If you do not have direct access to Magma, you can try this out
with the online Magma calculator at http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ .)

Comment: Could you explain 'By a 2-descent, one can show that the Jacobian variety of C′'?

Comment: @Arul : This is explained in detail in my paper "Implementing 2-descent for Jacobians of hyperelliptic curves" (Acta Arith. 98, 245-277, 2001). If you are familiar with 2-descent on elliptic curves, then it can be seen as a generalization of that: one computes the 2-Selmer group of the Jacobian as a subgroup of ${\mathbb Q}(\theta)^\times$ mod squares, where $\theta = \sqrt[5]{49/4}$. There is an injection of $J({\mathbb Q})/2 J({\mathbb Q})$ into the 2-Selmer group, so we obtain an upper bound for the rank.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that passage from $x^5+y^5=7$ to the hyperelliptic curve is achieved by rewriting as $x^{10}+(xy)^5=7x^5$ changing variables to $u=x^5$ and $v=xy$ and completing the square.

Answer (score 14):

In his 1825 paper, Lejeune Dirichlet proved that the equation $x^5 + y^5 = cz^5$ has no nontrivial solution with x and y coprime integers and z integer for a rather large class of integers c. His paper can be read on the site Gallica :
http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5842885h/f2.item.zoom
but the visualization is very bad.

Comment: It's actually not so bad already, but here is an improved OCRed file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jkbl5gtzdyuzktt/dirichlet.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Looking through Dirichlet's paper, it seems that he always assumes $c$ to be divisible by 2 or 5 (unless $c = 1$).

Comment: You are right. Dirichlet doesn't solve the problem for $c = 5$. My answer was rather a comment.

Comment: @Panurge meant to write "Dirichlet doesn't solve the problem for $c=7$".